How to compute the volume of a high-dimensional cube with complex and dependent coordinates?
I am reading
a paper on ideal lattices:

On page $15$ ( in the proof of Lemma $6.1$ ), it says:

The cube $\mathcal{C}_2 = \left\{\left(z,\bar{z}\right) \in \mathbb{C}^{2} : \left\vert z \right\vert \le 1\right\}$ is a two-dimensional closed disc of radius $\sqrt{2}$, so its volume is $2\pi$.
My questions is:
How to understand this volume with coordinates being complex number and one coordinate is dependent on another one ?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

When $\Bbb C^2$ is naturally  identified to $\Bbb R^4$, $\left\{\left(z,\bar{z}\right):z \in \mathbb{C}\right\}$ is identified to the plane $\left\{\left(x,y,x,-y\right):(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2\right\}$, with orthonormal basis $\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}\left(1,0,1,0\right),\frac1{\sqrt2}\left(0,1,0,-1\right)\right)$. In this basis, the subset $\mathcal C_2$ is defined by $\left|\frac X{\sqrt2}+i
\frac Y{\sqrt2}\right|\le1$,
i.e. $\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}\le\sqrt2$.

Thanks for your answer. I think it is quite clear! However, I would appreciate your help in verifying my understanding. (Please forgive my lack of basic background in geometry.) Here’s my understanding of your answer: 1) The volume must be computed via some orthonormal basis. 2) the factor $1/\sqrt{2}$ in the orthonormal basis (fundamentally) comes from the dependence of the coordinates. 3) Under the orthonormal basis, the change of coordinates is a kind of “shrinking” (or scaling of the axes), which leads to the final result. Is there any problem with my understanding?

I fully agree, except that there is no real 'scaling of the axes' (which would seem arbitrary). The basis of the plane which I provided is orthonormal  for the canonical inner product on  $\Bbb R^4$.

Thanks a lot! Could you recommend some textbooks where I can systematically learn the relevant background on geometry?

Sorry, I don't know. Hopefully someone else will read and answer your comment..
